# Mutual SSL authentication between AWS API Gateway and .NET Core

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to use an AWS API Gateway client certificate to authenticate to my backend services.

The backend services are running ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API.

I have created a client certificate in API Gateway and have configured each stage to use that certificate. I've copied the contents and have been able to create an instance of the `X509Certificate2` class in my project.

I have verified the value of Subject and Issuer via a unit test:

```
Assert.Equal("CN=ApiGateway, L=Seattle, C=US", x509Cert.Subject);
Assert.Equal("CN=ApiGateway, L=Seattle, C=US", x509Cert.Issuer);
```

I'm using `CWiz.ClientCertificateMiddleware` to perform the checking of the client certificate.

In `appsettings.json` I have the following config:

```
"AuthorizedCertficatesAndRoles": {
    "CertificateAndRoles": [
        {
            "Issuer": "CN=ApiGateway, L=Seattle, C=US",
            "Subject": "CN=ApiGateway, L=Seattle, C=US",
            "Roles": [
                "ApiGateway"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In `ConfigureServices`, I've added the following code:

```
            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCertificateAuthentication(certOptions =>
                {
                    var certificateAndRoles = new List<CertficateAuthenticationOptions.CertificateAndRoles>();

                    Configuration.GetSection("AuthorizedCertficatesAndRoles:CertificateAndRoles")
                        .Bind(certificateAndRoles);

                    certOptions.CertificatesAndRoles = certificateAndRoles.ToArray();
                });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CanAccessMethods", policy => policy.RequireRole("ApiGateway"));
            });
```

In my Controller, I've added the following attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessMethods")]
```

My listener is configured as follows:

```
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel(
                options =>
                {
                    options.AddServerHeader = false;
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        var httpsOptions = new HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions
                        {
                            ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate,
                            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls,
                            ServerCertificate = certificate
                        };

                        listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions);
                    });
                }
            )
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

The `certificate` is a Pfx file loaded from disk. Other services that don't yet have the client certificate authorization configured are working perfectly with a valid certificate shown in Chrome.

Once I deploy to a Linux Docker container in AWS ECS, if I try and request the API via the backend DNS, I correctly get a `401 Unauthorized`.

If I try and access the service via API Gateway, I get:

```
(372f75a4-ca9e-11e7-9e9a-3174ab436b5a) Execution failed due to an internal error
(372f75a4-ca9e-11e7-9e9a-3174ab436b5a) Method completed with status: 504
```

What do I need to do to get Client Certificate authentication/authorization working?

Comment: `504` is a timeout, which doesn't sound related to the certificate. Are you sure API Gateway has network access to the back-end server? The back-end has to be publicly accessible on the Internet.

Comment: I’m sure it has network access because with a version of the backend container without the client certificate code works successfully from the backend DNS and API Gateway.

Comment: Can you enable Cloudwatch log on your API to have more information for investigation?

Comment: Any luck resolving this?